# 404 error encountered when requesting a classic asp page in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I am converting a classic asp application to ASP.NET MVC3.

I have following route mappings in the global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute("LogOn", "Scripts/Logon", New With {.controller = "Account", .action = "Logon"})
routes.MapRoute("LogOnASP", "Scripts/Logon.asp", New With {.controller = "Account", .action = "Logon"})
routes.MapRoute("LogOnASPX", "Scripts/Logon.aspx", New With {.controller = "Account", .action = "Logon"})
```

Neither logon.asp nor logon.aspX exist in the folder “Scripts”.  But only logon.asp renders the 404 error. It seems that IIS checks if the logon.asp exists and reports 404 if no such a file.

How do I configure the IIS settings to allow an asp url to pass through?

I feel confused that my localhost IIS (Windows 7 64-bits), IIS 7.5) doesn’t render any error when I use the Logon.asp in a url.  The error is only rendered in the demo server (IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2 server).